# Loop images folder and resize them

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to loop trough a folder full of images and resize a copy of them inside another folder. It works fine when I try to do it with one of them but when I loop it, it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I don't get any errors.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

?>

    <?php

// exec('/usr/bin/convert /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/10114-20170610_211655_182.jpg -resize 340x340 /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/thumbnails/10114-20170610_211655_182.jpg');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads";
$result_set = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
    {
    $pic = $row['file'];

    // echo $pic;

    exec('/usr/bin/convert /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/$pic -resize 340x340 /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/thumbnails/$pic');
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `exec()` call, you should either use string concatenation or double quotes to get the interpreter to recognize your `$pic` variable.

```
exec('/usr/bin/convert /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/' . $pic . ' -resize 340x340 /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/thumbnails/' . $pic);
```

or

```
exec("/usr/bin/convert /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/$pic -resize 340x340 /home/forbes11/public_html/gallery/uploads/thumbnails/$pic");
```

Comment: Well picked up @James Meisler I always use double quotes with exec anyway as single quotes do not work on my windows localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the PHP and the database access is doing, but if you have a directory full of JPEG images that you want to resize and save the thumbnails in a new directory, you can do that very easily from the command-line with **ImageMagick**'s `mogrify` command:

```
mogrify -path /output/directory -resize 340x340 *.jpg
```

If the names of the files are coming from **MySQL**, you could pass them into `mogrify` on its `stdin`:

```
mysql_query_listing_filenames | mogrify -path /output/directory -resize 340x340 *.jpg @-
```